# How to store data in SqlLite database (JavaFX on Android)

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, javafxports

I created a small application in JavaFX and deployed it in my Android device using Gluon Plugin. One of the requirements of my application is to store data in SqlLite database. I know how to do it using Android SDK but I dont have any idea on how to do it in JavaFX. Need help!

Comment: [JDBC Database Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/)

Comment: Can you give a more detail on how to do it?

Comment: I gave you whole tutorial.  You will need a JDBC driver for SQLite, a google search should provide you with some ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Download](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads) and add the SQLite JDBC to your classpath.

Following it, create a connection :

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");  
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:somefilename.db");
```

You can replace `somefilename.db` with `somefilelocation\somefilename.db`, if you want to specify the location of the database file.

Then use the connection to create Statements and ResultSets to interact with the database. Everything is mentioned in the  [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/overview/index.html), @MadProgrammer just gave you.